# Magento AW blog subdomain to blog

Tags: magento

Hi we are on directadmin, have Magento and AW Blog

We can access the blog via magento.com/blog

Now how do I set it so that users can also access the blog via blog.magento.com

and that it feels like they are on the site blog.magento.com etc even when opening posts etc

UPDATE:
We setup a subdomain via directadmin blog.magento.com
(this creates a subdirectory blog under public_html, that I removed)
It needs to request magento.com/blog in the background 
via magento.com index.php that will it route to the blog route

Anyone experiences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried this particular task, so this is purely hypothetical. But assuming going to blog.magento.com currently directs to the same document root as the main domain you should simply be able to do this with .htaccess redirects.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.magento\.com
RewriteRule .* /blog/%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

This would need placing before the standard Magento redirect rules.

ADDITION:

It is important to setup the subdomain to the root of the domain (and not a sub directory). In Direct Admin this can be done, not via the option subdomain, but rather the option Add pointer. And then adding blog.domain.com as pointer

Comment: Gonna try this. Thx. Does the sub domain need to exist in dns. Accepting sub donains. Anything there to watch out for?

Comment: Experimenting

This code gives 500 error

So I tried 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.*$
# RewriteRule .* /blog/%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

Problem now is that blog.magento.com need to become www.magento.com/blog

A loop is created because the prefix blog triggers a next rewrite